# C# React web app Base generic CRUD controller not working

Tags: c#

I know this question has been asked before but I did try the solutions and they did not work. I have a `Base Generic Controller` that I would like to use for all my crud operations, pardon me if the logic is wrong but this is what I use in `Java`, in fact I basically converter my `Java` logic to `C#`. The idea is a base controller that uses generics to perform crud operations, I then create a specific controller that inherits from it, depending on whether that controller has extra methods then I can just add them in the child than have all the children with the same crud implementation.

Below is my BaseController

```
 public abstract class BaseController<V, K, T> : ControllerBase, IBaseController<V> where V : BaseDto where K : IBaseService<V>
{


    public abstract K GetService();


    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };


    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        var rng = new Random();
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
        .ToArray();
    }



    [HttpPost]
    public virtual async Task<ActionResult> Create(V v)
    {
        return Ok(await GetService().Create(v));
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Fetch(Guid id)
    {
        return Ok(await GetService().Fetch(id));
    }


    [HttpGet]
    public virtual async Task<ActionResult> Fetch(int page, int pageSize)
    {
        return Ok("Response: " + page + pageSize);
        // return Ok(await GetService().Fetch(page, pageSize));
    }


    [HttpPut]
    public virtual async Task<ActionResult> Update(V v)
    {
        return Ok(await GetService().Update(v));
    }


}
```

And simply inherit from it and pass the respective service and types like

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class UserController : BaseController<UserDto, UserServiceImpl, User>
{

    private readonly UserServiceImpl _userServiceImpl;
    private readonly ILogger<UserController> _logger;

    public UserController(ILogger<UserController> logger)
    {
        _userServiceImpl = new UserServiceImpl();
        _logger = logger;
    }


    public override UserServiceImpl GetService()
    {
        return _userServiceImpl;
    }
}
```

When I try to access any of my crud methods I get a `400` when I move a method `e.g` then `public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()` to the child and try to access it, I manage to but when I throw it in the `BaseController` I fail to access it.

What could be the reason?

Comment: Are you seeing any message in the response? Are you able to debug the code?

Comment: I am getting the error `{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"|dd46b4a7-479fc1f04bf2e69f.","errors":{"id":["The value 'favicon.ico' is not valid."]}}` in the log, according to MS [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-3.1) it means a `400`

Comment: @Nemo can you provide us with the code that's calling this action ?

Comment: I basically call it from the browser e.g `https://localhost:44398/api/user/create`

Comment: @Nemo try renaming the get method of the WeatherForecast its probably confusing it with other methods since you have multiple get methods. from what i see from the error, you're calling a method with a different signature or with the wrong parameters.